# c# Getting object elements with the same values that using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects named `LastFiles` and `DbObj`. When I pull the data, I have 2 object lists consisting of these. I created a scenario like this.

```
public class LastFiles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Translator { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public class DbObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
}

var lastFiles = new List<LastFiles> {
    new LastFiles { Id = 1, Title = "Title 1", Author = "Author 1", Type = "book", FileName = "file-name-1.pdf" },
    new LastFiles { Id = 2, Title = "Title 2", Author = "Author 2", Type = "book", FileName = "file-name-2.pdf" },
    new LastFiles { Id = 3, Title = "Title 3", Author = "Author 3", Type = "article", FileName = "file-name-3.pdf" },
    new LastFiles { Id = 4, Title = "Title 4", Author = "Author 4", Type = "article", FileName = "file-name-4.pdf" },
    new LastFiles { Id = 5, Title = "Title 5", Author = "Author 5", Supervisor = "Supervisor 1", Type = "thesis", FileName = "file-name-5.pdf" },
    new LastFiles { Id = 6, Title = "Title 6", Author = "Author 6", Supervisor = "Supervisor 2", Type = "thesis", FileName = "file-name-6.pdf" }
};

var dbObj = new List<DbObj> {
    new DbObj { Id = 1, WorkId = 5, Type = "book", TypeId = 1 },
    new DbObj { Id = 2, WorkId = 5, Type = "book", TypeId = 2 },
    new DbObj { Id = 3, WorkId = 5, Type = "thesis", TypeId = 5 },
    new DbObj { Id = 4, WorkId = 5, Type = "thesis", TypeId = 6 },
    new DbObj { Id = 5, WorkId = 278, Type = "article", TypeId = 689 }
};
```

If I have to go through the scenario; How can I get items from `lastFiles` that `LastFiles.Type` value is the same as the `DbObj.Type` value and the `LastFiles.Id` is the same as the `DbObj.TypeId`?

Comment: Are you looking to Join the two lists?

Comment: @gunr2171 - Frankly, I have no idea whether `join` will be used or not. I just want to get elements of `lastFiles` based on `dbObj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous object to join two collections like below :

```
var result = (from lf in lastFiles
                      join db in dbObj on new { lf.Type, TypeId = lf.Id}
                                   equals new  { db.Type, db.TypeId} 
                      select lf).ToList();
```

**Edit**

Lambda version of the join :

```
var result2 = lastFiles.Join(dbObj,lf=> new {lf.Type,TypeId = lf.Id},db=>new  { db.Type,db.TypeId},(lf,db)=> lf  ).ToArray();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TgXa1C)

Please note that property names and types should match. You may need renames and casts in actual code.

Comment: I know and support the Stackoverflow rules. Despite of this, I can't pass without thanks.

Comment: So how can we do this with lambda expression?

Comment: @HabipOğuz see the updated answer.